# How can I import an .fbx with multiple animations, split them automatically, and view them individually in the Action Editor?

Tags: animation, import, unity, .fbx, actions

Currently I’m importing a file and getting one action with all the animations concatenated together.
[Armature.fbx](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/4PMyoeM2yB09JsA1vvHX2lcVXgM.fbx) (4.8 MB) That's a standard Unity model that comes with a project from Unity Technologies.

Alternatively, could anybody point me in the direction of a professionally animated model for use in Unity that I can import into Blender and study for best practices? Trying to work out good naming conventions and methods for using the action editor...!